# bash variable as awk field width

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I have a variable: `n=$maxlen`, is there any way I can use that as the field width when using printf in awk?

Something like this:

```
n=$maxlen
awk -v val=$n -F',' '{printf "%vals %7s %17s %4i\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! :D

```
n=$maxlen
awk -v val=$n -F',' '{printf "%*s %7s %17s %4i\n", val, $1, $2, $3, $4}' somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to go behind AWK's back, and ask Bash to slip the number directly into the AWK script:

```
awk -v -F',' '{printf "%'"$n"'s %7s %17s %4i\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' somefile.txt
```

As far as AWK will ever know, that `%'"$n"'s` is an actual `%3s` (or whatever).

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, Thanks!